# Difference between char *string and char string[n]

Tags: c

I wrote a c code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char* string;
    char n;
    while(scanf("%s",string)!=EOF){
        
        printf("\n%s\n",string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

it shows an error by keep printing null. However it works when I change the
`char* string;`
into
`char string[50];`
What is the reason behind this?

The char string[n] is able to reprint whatever I write on the terminal

Comment: After the `char* string;` declaration, what memory is the pointer pointing to?

Comment: You need to study pointers before you move on to strings. Also `n` should be type `int`.

Comment: With your pointer variable `string`, it's not initialized. It doesn't point anywhere valid, and any attempt to dereference it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: `char string[50];` gives you memory where you can store 50 characters. `char* string;` gives you memory where you can store a char-pointer. The char pointer can then be assigned a value so that it points to memory where you can store characters.

Comment: `char *string;` allocates an uninitialized pointer. `char string[50];` allocates an array of 50 `char`s and `string` automatically decays into a pointer to the beginning of that array.

Comment: See the first **images** in this article https://www.w3resource.com/c-programming/c-arrays-and-pointers.php they give a graphical insight, which is too often overlooked in a written explanation